# Is $\mathbb{N}$ with the topology generated by the sets $\{ n,n+1,\ldots \}$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb N$ be equipped with the topology generated by the basis consisting of the sets $A_n=\{n,n+1,...\}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Is $X$ compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, \ldots \}$, note that the *only* open set containing $1$ is $A_1 = \{ 1, 2, \ldots \} = X$. Therefore *every* open cover of $X$ must contain $X$, and so has $\{ X \}$ as a finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Any open cover of $X$ must contain $A_1$.